# XSLT 1.0 - Acquire set of values not in second set

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Given two data sets (assume they are valid node-sets):

`$first` being

```
<values>
  <value id="1"/>
  <value id="2"/>
  <value id="3"/>
</values>
```

and `$second` being

```
<values>
  <value id="3"/>
  <value id="4"/>
  <value id="5"/>
</values>
```

Would I be able to construct an XPath in XSLT that selects exactly the `<value/>` nodes from `$first` that do NOT exist in `$second`?

The closest I've gotten, with minimal thought admittedly, was

```
$first/value[not(@id = $second/value/@id)]
```

However, it is obviously incorrect.  My next thought was along the lines of:

```
$first/value[not($second/value[@id = current()/@id])]
```

That also is distinctly incorrect, as `current()` references the context node, not the current `value` node.

Is there a single-line method that doesn't require ugly string manipulation to make this filter?  Is there a better more generic XSLT solution available?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is tagged XSLT 1.0 - so you could **not** do a `string-join`. Re your question, I suggest you study the XPath rules for comparison explained here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry, I had thought it was a part of 1.0.  Then that isn't an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your issue is. With this input:

```
<xml>
    <first>
        <values>
          <value id="1"/>
          <value id="2"/>
          <value id="3"/>
        </values>
    </first>
    <second>
        <values>
          <value id="3"/>
          <value id="4"/>
          <value id="5"/>
        </values>
    </second>
</xml>
```

this stylesheet

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="first" select="/*/first/values" />
    <xsl:variable name="second" select="/*/second/values" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <same>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$first/value[@id = $second/value/@id]" />
            </same>
            <different>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$first/value[not(@id = $second/value/@id)]" />
            </different>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

gives

```
<output>
   <same>
      <value id="3"/>
   </same>
   <different>
      <value id="1"/>
      <value id="2"/>
   </different>
</output>
```

Exactly as you seem to want, with exactly the code you have been using.